# How to plot multiple pie charts side-by-side in plotly from Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

How do you plot more than 2 pie charts using plotly? For example, how do you put two more plots in the two pie charts as seen [here](https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/):

```
`import plotly.plotly as py
 import plotly.graph_objs as go
 fig = {
 "data": [
{
  "values": [16, 15, 12, 6, 5, 4, 42],
  "labels": [
    "US",
    "China",
    "European Union",
    "Russian Federation",
    "Brazil",
    "India",
    "Rest of World"
  ],
  "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
  "name": "GHG Emissions",
  "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
  "hole": .4,
  "type": "pie"},     
{
  "values": [27, 11, 25, 8, 1, 3, 25],
  "labels": [
    "US",
    "China",
    "European Union",
    "Russian Federation",
    "Brazil",
    "India",
    "Rest of World"
  ],
  "text":"CO2",
  "textposition":"inside",
  "domain": {"x": [.52, 1]},
  "name": "CO2 Emissions",
  "hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
  "hole": .4,
  "type": "pie"
 }], 
 }}
       py.iplot(fig, filename='donut')
```

What does domain mean in this case? What are alternative ways to plot multiple pie charts using plotly?

Answer (score 0):

> What does domain mean in this case?

`domain` specifies in which rectangle the chart will be placed.

E.g., a `domain` of:

```
domain={'x': [0, .5], 'y': [0, 1.0]},
```

means:

- `'x': [0, .5]`: place the graph on the half left side of the image, i.e. from 0.0 to 0.5 of the total width.
- `'y': [0, 1.0]`: occupy the full height of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

import plotly.graph_objects as go

from plotly.offline import plot



fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}]])



fig.add_trace(go.Pie(values=[16, 15, 12, 6, 5, 4, 42],
     
     labels=["US", "China", "European Union", "Russian Federation",
             "Brazil", "India", "Rest of World"],
     
     domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5]),
     
     name="GHG Emissions"), 
              
              row=1, col=1)


fig.add_trace(go.Pie(values=[27, 11, 25, 8, 1, 3, 25],
     
     labels=["US", "China", "European Union", "Russian Federation",
             "Brazil", "India", "Rest of World"],
     
     domain=dict(x=[0.5, 1.0]),
     
     name="CO2 Emissions"),
              row=1, col=2)


plot(fig)
```